# Send POST value through AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Let's say I have the following code:

```
<a href="index.php">Link</a>
```

When the link is clicked I want it to pass on a POST value named *a* containing *b*, so that I on index.php can reach it with $_POST['a']. I understand that this is a job for AJAX, but how?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Did you try anything at all before asking this question?

Comment: You should ask questions about AJAX's detailed features and how to use them properly. Not how to use AJAX's basic mission.

Comment: Have you tried the following? http://bit.ly/yPwOpN

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX POST example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example)

Answer (score 1):

it is going to be something like this:

1. create a handler on the anchor
2. since you're using jQuery you can use the AJAX helpers. THere is a simpler "post" method in the [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) but i don't bother with it. (notice the statement about post() being shorthand version of ajax()

e.g.

```
$('a').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: {
            "a": "b"
        },
        success: function () {
            // a function called after POST   
        }  // end success
    }); // end ajax

    // optional code here that is run asynchronously from the POST above but also triggered by the click
           return false; 
}); // end on click
```

Comment: I can't seem to get your code to work. The link takes me to index.php, where I run print_r($_POST), but nothing is ever returned. I suspect that I haven't "created a handler on the anchor", whatever that means.

Comment: the handler in the the `'click'` event delegated by the `on()` method. Because you're using a link to index.php in the html I can't tell where your problem is.    Perhaps to keep things simple change your `a` (anchor) to a different element like a `p`.  Since we're adding a `click` handler we don't need to use the anchor's default event.  You won't get the nice finger-pointer but we're just simplifying things for now.   However,  i added a `return false` above though which should stop the default request. If you do stay with an anchor then maybe change it to `<a href="#">`

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to learn a little more about JQuery Ajax functions:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

The examples there should be a good start for what you want. Update your question if you have any specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at the [**jQuery.post()** documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). The 2nd example listed shows you how to pass data explicitly to a specific URL such as "index.php".